# How to specify which schema to use once?

Tags: java, jdbc, mysql-workbench, datasource, crud

I'm learning basic  CRUD in JDBC, MySql using local database and the problem is that for each crud method i have to specify which Schema to use.. Is there Any way to place it once?  This becomes a problem when i will test it with h2 database.

`
public class DbConnection implements ConnectionProvider{

```
private MysqlDataSource datasource = new MysqlDataSource();


/* FileNotFoundException,  setUseSSL= false not working
*TODO: fix fileNotFoundException , properties password and username error
*/
public DbConnection() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        //datasource.setUseSSL(false);
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/java/ConnectionSource.properties"));
    } catch (IOException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String password = properties.getProperty("password");
    String serverName = properties.getProperty("host");
    String user = properties.getProperty("user");
    datasource.setPassword(password);
    datasource.setUser(user);
    datasource.setServerName(serverName);
}

//For different Databases and users
public DbConnection(String password, String user, String serverName){
    datasource.setPassword(password);
    datasource.setUser(user);
    datasource.setServerName(serverName);
}


@Override
public Connection getConnection() throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    return datasource.getConnection();
}
```

}

`The Provider:`
public interface ConnectionProvider {

```
Connection getConnection() throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

}`

Where i Specify it: 
` public void createTableSubjects(MysqlDataSource dataSource) {

```
    FileReader file = new FileReader();
    file.readFromFileSubjects();
    String query = "CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS " + file.getItemFromList(1) + "( " +
            "  " + file.getItemFromList(2) + "       " + file.getItemFromList(22) + " unique not null," +
            "  " + file.getItemFromList(3) + "       " + file.getItemFromList(22) + " default 'null'," +
            "  " + file.getItemFromList(4) + "       " + file.getItemFromList(22) + " default 'null'," +
            "  " + file.getItemFromList(5) + "       " + file.getItemFromList(22) + " default 'null'," +
            "  " + file.getItemFromList(6) + "       " + file.getItemFromList(22) + " default 'null'," +
            "  " + file.getItemFromList(7) + "       " + file.getItemFromList(22) + " default 'null'," +
            "  PRIMARY KEY (" + file.getItemFromList(2) + ")" +
            ")";

    /**Så ingen poeng med å  bruke preparedStatement her**/
    try (Connection con = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("USE Time_edit"); //TODO: how to specify once only?
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        System.out.println("New Table 'Subjects' created");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to create Table 'Subjects' \n" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Set the database name on the data source:

```
datasource.setPassword(password);
datasource.setUser(user);
datasource.setServerName(serverName);
datasource.setDatabaseName("Time_edit");
```

Comment: That looked really like it was the solution , but it still says ' no database selected '  :/

Comment: i also added password to my workbench and changed password-value from empty to the new password in .properties-file and got the same problem. MysqlDataSource  cant register anything..

Comment: FIXED IT! thanks for helping.  The reason why none of the datasource methods worked was because i placed the .proprties file in wrong place. It should be placed inside resource folder  in Intellij ;)